# SQL Query to Search for String within a String (but the string may be separated)

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I can't figure out the SQL query that would be able to select a row based on a column containing a string but the string could be separated.

For example, the string I am searching for:

```
1345
```

Would match:

```
0123456
```

That includes 3 things:

1) Any string before

2) Any string after

3) Any string randomly in the middle

I have tried using the following queries

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE FileName LIKE %1345%

SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(FileName, '1345')
```

But these will not select if the string is randomly in the middle. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: @AvinashRaj is that using LIKE? And also, of course, the string would not be simple numbers so separating the characters like that could be difficult?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to pre-prepare for regexp match, so you produce a query like this

```
SELECT * from name1
WHERE name1.name REGEXP ".*a.*p.*a.*"
```

Comment: I don't understand how to implement this?

Comment: in order to match strings randomly in the middle of your criteria, you need to pre-prepare your criteria BEFORE sending the query using your favorite server side language, you'd append `.*` before and after each character so REGEXP operator works as expected. Just remember to escape user input tu prevent SQL attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution tested in MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE FileName LIKE '%1%2%3%';
```

It matches entries like

> 2004267695, 2005285881, 20060004841, 20060136398, 20080189084, and 20090189887.
>
> Folio 8 1/2 x 13 in
>
> 1992-2003